# Code returned an empty dataframe with data scraped from a website

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Below is the code I tried to run. It actually ran successfully without any error, just that it returned an empty dataframe.

```
# url link
url = "https://www.thestudio.com/product-catalog/"

# Use requests() function to get the url
response = requests.get(url)

# Use conditional statement to confirm if the site is active and 
# if it is, parse the content with BeatifulSoup
if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    product_names = [item.text for item in soup.select(".product-name")]

    # Create a DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Product Names": product_names})

    # Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
    df.to_excel("product_catalog.xlsx", index=False)
else:
    print("Error accessing the website. Status code:", response.status_code)



# Load the data from the excel file
df = pd.read_excel("product_catalog.xlsx")

# Check the data
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

This site has no any product-name class, try to get product name from parent class

```
 import requests
 import pandas as pd

 url = "https://www.thestudio.com/product-catalog/"

 response = requests.get(url)

 if response.status_code == 200:
     soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
     
     product_list = soup.find_all('h3', {'class': 'elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default'})
     product_names = [item.text for product in product_list for item in product.findChildren("a" , recursive=False)]

     # Create a DataFrame
     df = pd.DataFrame({"Product Names": product_names})

     # Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
     df.to_excel("product_catalog.xlsx", index=False)
 else:
     print("Error accessing the website. Status code:", response.status_code)



 df = pd.read_excel("product_catalog.xlsx")

 print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Anna Andreeva Rogotulka for your prompt response. The product names are now displayed with the 2 lines of code you provided.

Comment: @OlumideOlaoye i share all code it works and return product name

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct code:

```
# Use requests() function to get the url
response = requests.get(url)

# Use conditional statement to confirm if the site is active and 
# if it is, parse the content with BeatifulSoup
if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    product_list = soup.find_all('h3', {'class': 'elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default'})
    product_names = [item.text for product in product_list for item in product.findChildren("a" , recursive=False)]

    # Create a DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Product Names": product_names})

    # Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
    df.to_excel("product_catalog.xlsx", index=False)
else:
    print("Error accessing the website. Status code:", response.status_code)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).